# how to make array_sum by using specific key in php

Tags: php, arrays

**My array**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [53] => 5330 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [52] => 5967.64 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [52] => 700 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [58] => 1716 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [58] => 19901.68 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [58] => 77057.67 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [58] => 32955.96 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [58] => 88353 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [58] => 7163.52 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [58] => 9141.49 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [58] => 7796.12 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [59] => 62497.58 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [59] => 80800.19 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [59] => 209577.64 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [59] => 213654.6 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [59] => 67041.76 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [59] => 56507.14 ) )
```

So what I'm trying to do is add the values from each array with the same `key` values.

**For example:**

if the key is 53 I want the output: `5300`
if my key is 52 I want the output: `5967.64 + 700  = 6667.64`

This is the code I have tried so far, but it does not work. How can achieve what I want?

```
    $totalprofitamountstaffe = array(); 
            foreach($profitamountstaff as $key=>$profitamountstaffvalue){                       
            foreach($profitamountstaffvalue as $skey=>$profitstafffetch){
                $totalprofitamountstaffe[][$skey] = $profitstafffetch;
            }
            }

            print_r(array_values($profitamountstaff));  

            print_r($totalprofitamountstaffe);
            for($f=0;$f<count($totalprofitamountstaffe);$f++){
                    $totalprofitarray = $totalprofitamountstaffe[$f];   
            }


                 for($f=0;$f<count($totalprofitamountstaffe);$f++){
                        // $totalprofitarray = $totalprofitamountstaffe[$f];    
                 }
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: Why your code's commented?

Comment: @QuestionUser Google: `PHP array_column()`

Comment: what i have tried i just put it here so please give me an answer for this

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to give you an answer since your question makes no sense. *if my key is like 53 myoutput = 5300; if my key is like 52 myoutput = 5967.64 + 700  = 6667.64;* did not make your issue clear for me, and I sincerely doubt it's clear for anyone else.

Comment: Besides, your array is huge and is poorly formatted to fit as readable information. It demands more time trying to understand your problem than thinking about solutions for it. Please, consider reviewing its entire content to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this [array_column](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp)

```
 $arraysum = array_column($yourarray,'52');
 array_sum($arraysum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$new = array();
foreach($yourArray as $v) {
   foreach($v as $k => $val){
     if(array_key_exists($k, $new)) {
        $new[$k] += $val;
     }
     else
     {
        $new[$k] = $val;
     }
   }
}

var_dump($new);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [53]=>
  int(5330)
  [52]=>
  float(6667.64)
  [58]=>
  float(244085.44)
  [59]=>
  float(690078.91)
}
```